# Как поменять цвет со стандартного черного на белый и убрать opacity в свайпере в min.css?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // Цикличность
  loop: true,
  // Пагинация
  pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true
  },
  a11y: {
      paginationBulletMessage: 'Тут название слайда {{index}}',
  }
});
```

```css
.swiper__box{
position: relative;
height: 600px;
overflow: hidden;

}

.swiper-container{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: aqua;

}

.swiper-slide{
height: 100%;

}



.slide-img{
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}


.swiper-pagination{
padding-bottom: 70px;
color: #fff;
} 

.swiper-pagination-bullet{
opacity: 1;

}
```

```html
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@600;700&family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/10.3.0/swiper-bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-QokzG/B/9i5X3BYbmuyNn2ah9EiApK5KY4saOYZRCQINuB+X52ED0L3RCc/1x7YUA85qaFZ9uoB4x5SmkLGCJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/10.3.0/swiper-bundle.min.css" integrity="sha512-ryx4QW6sYyQthh6MIGW1cDEfNuIwTsvWtORXg5t3sqmh3TSNmqMr+VBN5N0T+z0GqqsiDJ5O8YhP4diuBGmcrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

</head>
<body>


<div class="swiper__box">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <!-- Slides -->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос касается dot - то достаточно повысить приоритет стилей для них добавлением дополнительного родительского класса `.swiper__box` и определить все что нужно.

```
.swiper__box .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // Цикличность
  loop: true,
  // Пагинация
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true
  },
  a11y: {
    paginationBulletMessage: 'Тут название слайда {{index}}',
  }
});
```

```css
.swiper__box {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.swiper-slide {
  height: 100%;
}

.slide-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  color: #fff;
}

.swiper__box .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #fff;
}

.swiper__box .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@600;700&family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/10.3.0/swiper-bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-QokzG/B/9i5X3BYbmuyNn2ah9EiApK5KY4saOYZRCQINuB+X52ED0L3RCc/1x7YUA85qaFZ9uoB4x5SmkLGCJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/10.3.0/swiper-bundle.min.css" integrity="sha512-ryx4QW6sYyQthh6MIGW1cDEfNuIwTsvWtORXg5t3sqmh3TSNmqMr+VBN5N0T+z0GqqsiDJ5O8YhP4diuBGmcrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="swiper__box">
    <div class="swiper-container">
      <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img class="slide-img" src="image/slider__bg.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- If we need pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !!!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант выше конечно же рабочий, но чтобы редактировать какие-то значения в **Swiper** иногда можно воспользоваться переменными, что сам Swiper предоставляет в документации, например для модуля [Pagination](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#pagination-css-custom-properties).

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },
});
```

```css
@import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css);

.swiper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color: #fff;
  --swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Такое решение может быть более чистым, особенно если планируется использовать различные темы.